# How to give name to a CLI instead of running via java <classpath>

Tags: java, maven, deployment, command-line-interface, jcommander

I am building a Command-line-interface using JCommander. Its a maven project.
I have a main which is doing all the controls. 
suppose, my application main java file is - AbcMain.java. 
I can run it as- 
       javac AbcMain.java
       java AbcMain

What I want is, to be able to run as any other command - 
     AbcMain

i.e. not have to run via java command.

Comment: The simple solution is to write a shell script whose name is `AbcMain`, etcetera.

Comment: yeah. that is one way. but looking for more cleaner way. Can maven do something similar to this?

Comment: AFAIK, no.  Though I'm sure you could write a Maven plugin to generate scripts for you.